# GWT TreeItem(String) constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am starting to work on a project coded by someone else. In this project, there are several

```
new TreeItem("some text")
```

and

```
someTreeItem.addItem("subitem")
```

Now, after installation of GWT plugin (I had some trouble that I don't understand, and several invalid GWT sdk...), eclipse tells me that `TreeItem(String)` is undefined, as well as `addItem(String)`.

I have the felling that I installed a newer version (hopefully not an older one) of GWT. So my questions are:

1. Is that a change in GWT API?
2. How should I replace `new TreeItem(String)̀  and`addItem(String)`?

Note:

I found [that page](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeItem.html) which has the "string" API and [that page](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html) that correspond the the API I have.

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the correct `TreeItem`? SWT also has a `TreeItem`

Comment: well the code has `import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `new TreeItem("some text")` and `addItem("some text")` with

```
TreeItem item = new TreeItem();
item.setText("some text");
myTree.addItem(item);
```

and

```
myTree.addTextItem("some text");
```

respectively.

Comment: Is that the equivalent? Is it the expected adaptation from a previous API ? I am starting with gwt and I can only guess what those are/were doing.

Comment: These are the changes in the library - your project must have used a very old version.

Comment: Strange because it was coded 2years ago max. But maybe the Guy used a version he was used to... well thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1) Most probably the version that you have imported does not support this constructor, for that you need to check the documentation.

2) Otherwise just check the .classpath file in project folder and check which version of gwt is being used there and update path to newer one.

Hope this helps.